# Read text file (containing list of Python filenames) and kill Python job if Python file appears in text file

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains names of Python files.

```
a.py
b.py
...
z.py
```

My remote machine may be currently running one of those files and if it is, I would like to kill that job. Is there a way to do that in one line automatically, without manually checking `htop` and looking at the current Python file being run, checking if it is part of the text file, and subsequently `kill pid`?

Comment: Is calling `ps aux | grep a.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9` okay, or do you want to avoid depending on `os.system` or something similar?

Comment: Running `ps aux | grep ... | xargs kill` is fine, but I don't know if `a.py` is the file currently running. There is 1 unknown file running and I would like to check it with all of the lines in the text file. If that file is running and it is part of the text file, then I would like to kill it.

Comment: This can show current running process. 

`ps -ef | grep python`
`ps` stands for process status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try placing all the contents of the text file in a list, and iterate through that list to delete that particular file.

```
import os

file_list = [x.strip("\n") for x in open("file_containing_pys.txt","r")]

for file in file_list:
    os.system("sudo kill $(ps aux | grep 'python %s.py' | awk '{ print $2 }')"%file)
```

/ogs

Answer (score 1):

There's a utility called `psutil`. Check it out [here](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/README.rst).

And then if that's what you're looking for, try the one below to list all the running python process.

```
import psutil

for p in psutil.get_process_list():
    if 'python' in str(p.name).lower():
        print p.cmdline
```